# If I am the administrator do I still have to type in the administrator username and password after UAC?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I just have a simple question. If I am the administrator of a computer with an admin username and password set, do I still have to type in the admin username and password in the prompt?

Comment: If you are running this computer in a standard user, then yes you will need to enter credentials. If you are running this computer (workstation) as an administrator user, then you should not have to enter credentials.  If a different admin set up the item and you log in as a different admin, you may have to enter credentials

Comment: Note that an User with admin-elevation capability (a user who can become admin for a time using UAC), then you can configure the system to either prompt you for credentials (and you just put in your username/passwd again) or to display a Yes/No option, so you could just click Yes. I believe that the default is to prompt for credentials if you are not an elevatable user (an admin), and to display the yes/no options if you are elevatable. if this system is administered by another party, they may have choosen to request credentials. the CSI layer 1 hardening advice for windows is to prompt.